# Getting value from anonymous type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Let's say we've got the following method:

```
public object Test()
{
    return new { A = "Test" };
}
```

Is there a chance of getting the value that is stored in **A**?

```
var b = Test(); //Any chance to cast this to the anonymous type?
```

Comment: Anonymous types were designed to be consumed in the same scope that they were created in.  Trying to do this is using it for something that it wasn't designed for, and as a result it is highly ineffective as a technique; you should avoid ever putting yourself in that position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note that returning anonymous types or `Tuple<>` from a method is a bad thing to do**

But you asked a question about how to do it, not about "is it a good idea"...

By using dynamic or reflection...

```
dynamic b = Test();
string str = b.A;
```

Or by cheating:

```
public static object Test()
{
    return new { A = "Test" };
}

public static string GetA(object obj)
{
    // We create an anonymous type of the same type of the one in Test()
    // just to have its type.
    var x = new { A = string.Empty };

    // We pass it to Cast, that will take its T from the type of x
    // and that will return obj casted to the type of the anonymous
    // type
    x = Cast(x, obj);

    // Now in x we have obj, but strongly typed. So x.A is the value we
    // want
    return x.A;
}

public static T Cast<T>(T type, object obj) where T : class
{
    return (T)obj;
}

string str = GetA(Test());
```

In C# all the anonymous types with the same properties of the same type that are in the same assembly are merged together. So the `new { A }` of `Test()` and of `GetA()` are of the same type.

The `Cast<T>` is a useful trick to extract the type from an anonymous type. You pass as the first parameter your typed anonymous type (the parameter is used only to "activate" the generic `T`) and as the second parameter the object you want to cast. Similar tricks can be used to create collections of generic types, like

```
public static T MakeList<T>(T type)
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> //Any chance to cast this to the anonymous type?

Yes, you can use cast by example.

```
public static T CastByExample<T>(this object obj, T example) {
     return (T)obj;
}
```

Note that this *only* works if you're in the same assembly. Anonymous types have the same type if they are the same assembly, and the properties have the same names of the same type in the same order.

Then:

```
object b = Test();
var example = new { A = "example" };
var casted = b.CastByExample(example);
Console.WriteLine(casted.A);
```

Alternatively, you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic b = Test();
Console.WriteLine(b.A);
```

Or, use reflection:

```
object b = Test();
var property = b.GetType().GetProperty("A");
var value = property.GetValue(b);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

**Or, you could just do the right thing and make a nominal (i.e., non-anonymous) type**.

Answer (score 0):

> Any chance to cast this to the anonymous type?

Although you can do that but it is highly unreliable. Because whenever you will change your creation of anonymous type your code will suddenly break on other places without a trace.

You can read all the downfalls of casting anonymous types in blog by Jon Skeet [here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx). Also worth reading are the comments by Marc Gravel.

**Example** of breaking change as discussed in the above blog.

```
using System;

static class GrottyHacks
{
    internal static T Cast<T>(object target, T example)
    {
        return (T) target;
    }
}

class CheesecakeFactory
{
    static object CreateCheesecake()
    {
        return new { Fruit="Strawberry", Topping="Chocolate" };
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        object weaklyTyped = CreateCheesecake();
        var stronglyTyped = GrottyHacks.Cast(weaklyTyped,
            new { Fruit="", Topping="" });

        Console.WriteLine("Cheesecake: {0} ({1})",
            stronglyTyped.Fruit, stronglyTyped.Topping);            
    }
}
```

All good. Now what if you suddenly realise that you need to change CreateCheeseCake to something like this

```
static object CreateCheesecake()
    {
        return new { Fruit="Strawberry", Topping="Chocolate", Base = "Biscuit" };
    }
```

Then what will happen to your this line

```
var stronglyTyped = GrottyHacks.Cast(weaklyTyped,
            new { Fruit="", Topping="" });
```

it won't work anymore.